# Trouble submitting to a REST API - only with Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

I've got a pretty simple jQuery/AJAX GET snippet that's used to enter a user that fills out a form into a CRM database we use.

```
 jQuery.get("https://www.website.com/RESTForm.aspx", {
     Customer : "ch000096151eArad", 
     Email : "1", 
     ownerid : "8", 
     overwrite : "0", 
     rurl : "http://www.website.com", 
     FirstName : jQuery('#firstname').val(), 
     LastName : jQuery('#lastname').val(), E
     mail : jQuery('#business_email').val(), 
     Company : jQuery('#COMPANY_NAME').val(), 
     LogIn_Name__c : jQuery('#loginname').val(),  
     Title : jQuery('#position').val(), 
     MailingStreet : jQuery('#business_address').val(), 
     MailingStreet2 : jQuery('#business_address2').val(), 
     MailingCity : jQuery('#business_city').val(), 
     MailingState : "GA", 
     MailingZip : jQuery('#business_zip').val(), 
     MailingCountry : jQuery('#business_country').val(), 
     Source : "Member", 
     CRMType: "Contact", 
     Institute_Membership__c: "Free Member" 
} );
```

The form submits successfully in every browser but Firefox, where in the console I get:

```
GET https://www.website.com/RESTForm.aspx [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 236ms]
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: 
The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.website.com/RESTForm.aspx. 
This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

Firefox doesn't seem to like me submitting it to another domain, but I'm unsure what to do with this information. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a client-side security measure to prevent client-side code from accessing multiple websites without the user knowing about it. Consider, for example, one tab in your browser where you're logged in to your bank account, and a different tab containing malicious code trying to transfer money from your account by some javascript code which uses your cookies from the other tab!

One fix is to allow the "remote" website (https://www.website.com) to accept requests from the original website. You can do so by returning an additional header,

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Or, which is safer,

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: url of original website

From the 'GET' handler of the remote website. You can read more about this in this nice [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Comment: This is good to know--I appreciate your help. Why do you think I can do it successfully with every other browser?

Comment: I believe ALL browsers require website owners to make additional effort (like what you're facing now) to support cross-site POST or PUT requests, which typically involve manipulating data (see under "Preflight Requests" in the above link). Additionally, no browser will let you move cookies around, as in the example I provided above. Therefore, without cookies, POST or PUT requests, I presume little damage can be done by malicious code just by running GET queries between websites. This is probably why most browsers don't prevent you from doing so.

Comment: I'd say that if security is a concern (which it should be) `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` should **never** be used. A OmegaDirective points out, second example is safer - and recommendable over the first. But, if you want to use JavaScript/jQuery to submit this petition, consider the postMessage method. Otherwise, why not do it with cURL (check out the cURL PHP library)

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much already have your answer:

```
The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.website.com/RESTForm.aspx. 
This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

You can either submit to the same domain as your web page or change the request type. For instance you may be able to do a regular (non XHR) request.